# Unable to launch MVC project (Unable to connect)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, model-view-controller

I have project running most fo the time OK several times occured problem, so i know some repair steps but still can not fix it.

Now i have not build project for about two weeks and now I can not debug it..
or connect to iisexpress or something..

This is what i have already tried:

- deleting folders like .vs bin and obj
- cleaning and rebuilding project
- creating virtual directory
- changing port for project
- emptying symbol cache and setting Microsoft Symbol Servers
- reinstalling IISExpress
- repairing whole Visual Studio
- VS is running as Administrator

there are no errors with building but there is a lot of Cannot find or open the PDB file messages.
Project runs if I hit ctrl+f5

EDIT:
I can see something strange now it loads my page after several reloads or going forward and backwards. It seems that there is too long respond time but if I look at diagnostic in VS it took 12MB of RAM and 0% of CPU..

Have anybody faced something like that???

EDIT 2:
I run it once when i checked microsoft symbols server but when i stopped it will not start again I do not really know what to do.

OUTPUT window:

```
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\x64\aswhooka.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\AcLayers.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sfc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sfc.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winspool.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sfc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sfc_os.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\fltLib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\rtinfo.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpresshelper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisutil2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\nativrd2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\xmllite.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ktmw32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dpapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisres.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisres.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisres.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mlang.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x10e0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xc28 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\hwebcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\w3wphost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120_clr0400.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iiscore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\normaliz.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\w3tp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\w3dt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\secur32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\httpapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0xdf0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\loghttp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\cachuri.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\cachtokn.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\compdyn.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\compstat.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\defdoc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\dirlist.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\protsup.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\redirect.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iis_ssi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\static.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\authanon.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\authcert.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\urlauthz.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\authbas.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\authsspi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\netapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wkscli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\authmap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iprestr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\diprestr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\modrqflt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\logcust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\custerr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisfreb.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisreqs.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wsock32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\isapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\filter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\cgi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisfcgi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\rewrite.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\validcfg.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iiswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\webmatrixsup.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\warmup.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\aspnetcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winhttp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll'
```

Comment: " can not debug it.. or connect to iisexpress or something" and " lot of Cannot find or open the PDB file messages" are not explanations of your issue. Please take the time to expalin your issue and post exact error messages

Comment: There are no error messages except "Unable to connect" in browser. I have edited question and added some new observings..

Comment: @j.j.a.c.k. everything after the second paragraph isn't helpful at all. If IIS Express isn't running you can't connect. *Can* you build your project in the first place? Did you hit F5 to start debugging, I assume using IIS Express? If your project crashes, the browser has nothing to connect to

Comment: BTW reinstalling Visual Studio, IIS Express, modifying the system will probably lead to *more* problems and won't fix the broken project. Can you create a *new* project? Can you run it?

Comment: Have you tried running it _without_ debugging (CTRL-F5). I'm pretty sure PDB is a debugging-only thing

Comment: So ctrl+F5 runs it but only once i created new project and it is running without problems I tried to load my project on my notebook and it runs without problems so is there something on my PC that can broke it?

Comment: You have got so many permutations of thing's you've tried so who knows. Stop randomly trying different things and actually try to understand and solve the root problem, which is probably the PDB file thing

Comment: I find out that pdb files are not important because this is not what i want to debug. Problem has to be elsewhere.. because now i am able to run project with ctrl+F5 but can not debug it.I am unable to find any error message can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols in Visual Studio and select Microsoft Symbol servers, it will try to download the correct pdb files for you. You could also load it manually from the Debug Modules window.

Reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6814e9de-b1b7-4012-af7b-d99758fa3013/getting-error-cannot-find-or-open-pdb-fle-when-debugging-in-visual-studio?forum=TFService

Uncheck "Native debugging" in Project Properties->Web, and check the ASP.NET debugger there.

Comment: already tried all pdb files downloaded finally but iisexpress pdb file stil could not load.. this could be The problem i think..

Comment: @j.j.a.c.k., Could you find the symbols/assembly in your cache folder? Could you load it manually from the Debug Modules window? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c8f14c9.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, please also run your VS as the admin.